# Haskell concurrency and persistence

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I've been reading the [Beautiful Concurrency](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/simonpj/beautiful-concurrency) article about Haskell and [STM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory).

The example given is a bank-account transfer.

Its a noddy bank transfer - its between two numbers sitting in heap memory.

The questions this immediately raises in my head are:

1. how that transfer atomically hits disk.  Until a bank transaction is recorded in a persistent - [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) - manner, it hasn't happened in my book.  How do people using languages like Haskell - which won't let you do any IO inside an STM - actually really do atomic changes in data that isn't only in volatile memory?
2. how to distribute this over many machines; how can you have distributed transactions and a scaling sideways application (without IO inside the STM)?

Comment: As answers imply I think the banking example is supposed to be understood as a metaphor

Comment: @jberryman so what is it useful for then?  What would be a more representative problem?  Below, we have two answers and the comments of one talk about stm-io-hooks which suggest 1) that stm might work with io, and that 2) this isn't very well known in the haskell community even, or 3) there's a flaw in that that hasn't been exposed here yet...

Comment: STM is useful when you have concurrency and implementing what you want with locks is non-trivial. I think you might get some really interesting answers if your question were more focused.

Answer (score 10):

STM is intended for thread synchronisation and communication, *not* for persistent storage of data. In other words, STM is designed to let threads share data between themselves without deadlocks or race conditions. Or for threads to send signals to each other. Or basically to coordinate thread activities.

If you want *persistent* data stored on disk, use a database. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc. There's a million to choose from. This is not the problem that STM is designed to solve.

For *distributed* processing... we're still working on that. I don't follow these things closely enough to comment on how close this is to being a reality.

Comment: Where does this stand with Don's link to stm-io-hooks?

Answer (score 7):

> How do people using languages like Haskell - which won't let you do any IO inside an STM - actually really do atomic changes in data that isn't only in volatile memory?

Via libraries in the IO or similar effect type. E.g. ACID or ["MACID"](http://happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/AcidState.html) systems.

> how to distribute this over many machines; how can you have distributed transactions and a scaling sideways application (without IO inside the STM)?

I don't know of a distributed STM implementation for Haskell, however [Cloud Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cloud_Haskell) is a distributed programming model for GHC.

Comment: for (1) you mean they don't use STM?  Is it classic locking in the IO libraries instead?

Comment: GHC's in-memory STM is used for some disk-based libraries. Sometimes the libraries themselves implement transactional semantics (e.g. databases). http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-io-hooks